# Visual Studio 2012 opening forms when application is not running

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am having a very strange issue with VS 2012. When in design time of a winform application if I open a specific form the login form appears on the screen, not as in designer, but as if the application had been launched.

I can open the login form in design time
[image: The login form in design time]

but when I open another form called Print this happens [image]

Clearly the form I have tried to open has not opened in the designer, and instead the application seems to have been launched. If I interact with the form by closing it then visual studio crashes. Also in the task manager the process is Devenv.exe.

I have tried clearing the obj and bin folders with no luck.

Comment: Very odd. Try putting some code in your Login form to display the call stack when it's opened, see where it's coming from?

Comment: You are tring to open Print.cs form and VS will start the program? Is this your problem?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes thats it. It works fine when designing login.cs and only when designing Print.cs

Comment: @RyanAmies: Does the code of the Print form contain some code that shows the login form?

Comment: Turns out `Print.cs` inherited from a different form which had code to launch `Login.cs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some initializers in an `_Load`-method of the second form which for example ask for a login, the thing will be executed.

You can check for the following 3 points in '_Load' of 2. form, if any occurs just do not execute the code in '_Load'.

```
this.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) !=null

System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode == System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any code changes or Process name checks, just move the GUI-related code from constructor to the Form Shown Event handler.